# How to configure Microsoft Exchange email account using Thunderbird on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, exchange

I have my work email that works on Windows and Microsoft Outlook. I tried Thunderbird on Windows and the email account works properly. Then, I installed Ubuntu and tried to configure my account in Thunderbird with the mail server that I found in my Outlook settings. The account was found but it kept failing to login. The message was an authentication failure "unrecognized user name or bad password". I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting *"unrecognized user name or bad password"*, you don't have a problem with the authentication method.

You're probably using the full email address as username in the server login, which will not work. Try

```
Windowns Domain\Windows Login
Windows Login
```

Either should work.

Comment: I will try adding the domain to the user. Just the way I login to the windows machine Domain\username. I wan only trying to add username and password without the domain. Thanks.